# Compilation fails due to missing file sys/utsname.h

Tags: visual-c++

I'm not a programmer in CPP but I'm trying to mess with code and receives the following error

"fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sys/utsname.h': No such file or directory"

there are libraries that need to download besides the installation of Visual Studio that contain the files that I was missing?

Answer (score 3):

`<sys/utsname.h>` is a POSIX header and does not exist on Windows (at least not in the Windows or Visual C++ SDKs).  It sounds a lot like this code you are trying to mess with is not designed to be compiled for Windows.  You could try using MinGW or Cygwin (though my installation of MinGW doesn't have that header either).  Otherwise, you'll need to modify the code or use a platform that has that header.